# AS3 Trace an info message

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm a AS3 developer but I'm not sure how can I trace this kind of messages in firebug as an [info](http://d.pr/i/9pWs) messsages.

I know that for an error I just need to inherit for an error but I'm not sure how can I trace this kind of messages.

This code:

```
trace("Hola")
```

will show "Hola" in Firebug, but I want the fancy Info icon at the beginning also the background of the line is blue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I may not understand the question, but have you heard of the global method `trace()`?

Comment: Referring to your update: I assume you mean that you want to create a dialogue for your traced messages?

Comment: That's right, but as you can see this dialogue is a default dialogue from firebug so maybe is just an special tag or something so it will show it like that

Comment: firebug alone won't show debug information. the debug information is listed in a file somewhere on your computer. There are tools that access that info, and I listed them below. But it you could also put in a debug window in your application that is accessed by a special key combination, I've done this with minimalcomps on a few projects

Comment: I am curious as to what the advantage of the fancy icon and blue background is :) Consider using some good tools that have a relatively fancy interface like http://demonsterdebugger.com/

Comment: The thing is that I'm going to release a version of a framework and I see in several projects from Google that they are using this trace ( with the info icon ) and well I  want to put it as a must and well if Google standardize this kind of information, well that will be great to have this.

Answer (score 1):

you can try https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashbug/

years ago I've used http://www.sephiroth.it/firefox/flashtracer/ not sure if anyone uses it still.

The trick is to use Debug version of flash player

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you don't want to install the Flash Debug player (performance?), rather than using trace, route it to a Debug method that traces and logs to the console:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
var debug:Boolean = true;
function log(msg:String):void {
    if ( debug ) {
        trace(msg);
        ExternalInterface.call('console.log',msg);
    }
}
log('Hello World');
```

You should be able to throw that in a frame. If you're using class definitions, you'll have to interpret that code block as snippets.

Also note that in a browser that doesn't have console.log (like IE7) this will throw an error, so maybe you should test for console.log first and store the result in a global.

Notice the debug variable. When you want to turn debug logging off, just set debug to false. This is an overly simplified idea, but provides the basic concept.

Another way enhance this concept is to include a debug "window" if you will... really just a scrollable text box on top of everything else. This is helpful when dealing with devices that do not support logging, debug versions of flash or are just difficult to debug, e.g. mobile and AIR.